# Definitions for Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

new to selenium and trying to do a repeating job with selenium but when ı put the commands in a definition it doesn't work. Without definition there is no problem with the code. So, what is the thing I am missing?

```
def repeat(self):
   firstframe.click()
   time.sleep(3)
   takipet.click()
   time.sleep(3)
   sonrakine.click()
   time.sleep(2)
    
   repeat(self)
```

Comment: To do any tasks repeatively you need to use any kind of loop,From above lines of codes it is difficult to tell what's your really scope here..

Comment: Why are you using the "self" param while calling the function? What error message do you get?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass in "self". This could be the problem.

```
def repeat():
    firstframe.click()
    time.sleep(3)
    takipet.click()
    time.sleep(3)
    sonrakine.click()
    time.sleep(2)

repeat()
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's because you're using 'self' in the wrong way.

Let's start with an easy example. This works:

```
def printTest():
    print('Test')

printTest()
```

This raises an Error:

```
def printTest(self):
    print('Test')
    
printTest(self)
```

To make it work, you have to do something like:

```
class Printing():
    
    def __init__(self): 
        self.text = 'Test' 
    
    def printTest(self):
        print(self.text)
    

p1 = Printing()

p1.printTest()
```